# ProcessReleaseResources

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, purescript, react-native-fbsdk

I am trying to build my react-native project and using react-native-fbsdk.

I am using react-native@0.38.0 and, react-native-fbsdk@0.5.0.

When I build my project I got this error on execution screen.

```
**Execution failed for task** ':react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseResources'.

com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/sathish/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' **finished with non-zero exit value 1**
```

Comment: make sure you have 23.0.1 build tools downloaded in android sdk.

Comment: ya..already i checked that.

Comment: Add more information here. Right now it's just an error log.

Comment: @RN 0.44, same here, don't know what happened, it was working just fine last week...

Comment: @peerless i found some temporary solution. check it bellow comment

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution for that.

`react-native-fbsdk` module was updated a few days ago, causing this error to occur.

if you want to resolve this error then do the following:

1. Go to your node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build.gradle.
   open build.gradle file.
2. Change `compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4++')` to `compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')`

Comment: It worked for me after upgrading the react-native to latest version : 0.44.2

Answer (score 3):

Was able to fix it by updating the react-native-fbsdk to 0.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

This works but even using it and RN 0.45 it was kind of temporary. If I upgraded a module I would have to reapply the fix. I found [this](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-android/issues/316) and it seems like a better fix. Should be updated in the main RN repo though.

Comment: The link in this answer is 404. 