# React-native fbsdk build errors

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, react-native, android-facebook, react-native-fbsdk

I am getting the following errors while running the command react-native run-android or ./gradlew build

```
:react-native-fbsdk:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-fbsdk:generateReleaseResources
:react-native-fbsdk:mergeReleaseResources
:react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseManifest
:react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseResources
/Users/a/projects/gratisapp/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
/Users/a/projects/gratisapp/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/25.3.1/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml:2 : Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

:react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/a/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 15.614 secs
```

Here is my `app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"]
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gratisapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
//  compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')){
//    exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
//  }
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
//    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.getRequested().getGroup() == 'com.google.android.gms') {
            // If different projects require different versions of
            // Google Play Services it causes a crash on run.
            // Fix by overriding version for all projects.
            details.useVersion('9.6.1')
        }
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

I have also tried with `compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')` but it doesnt work.
I see that it is trying to get a resource from version 25.3.1, but why? And how do I fix this problem? Any suggestions regarding this?

Thanks

---

### UPDATE

After the suggestion in the comments, here is my android/build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

project(':react-native-fbsdk') {
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
      force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
    }
  }
}
```

and my app/build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"]
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gratisapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
//  compile(project(':react-native-fbsdk')){
//    exclude(group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk')
//  }

  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
//    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
//  compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.getRequested().getGroup() == 'com.google.android.gms') {
            // If different projects require different versions of
            // Google Play Services it causes a crash on run.
            // Fix by overriding version for all projects.
            details.useVersion('9.6.1')
        }
    }
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

And I get the error for running the comman `./gradlew clean build:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 25.0.3

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

---

### UPDATE 2

So, after some suggestions given in the comments below, here is my android/app/build.gradle:
https://pastebin.com/q5qfHAug
and my android/build.gradle:
https://pastebin.com/GmckcqLb
and I am getting errors:
https://pastebin.com/JHe6XzzB

Comment: The solution posted here works for me: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235408/processreleaseresources)

Comment: @FacundoBazzana no, it doesnt work. I have tried it already.

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332749/react-native-not-running-on-android-post-update/44332935#44332935

Comment: @G0dsquad nope it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried updating to a higher `buildToolsVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to match your error above? E.g. `compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"`

Comment: @G0dsquad I have updated my answer, it gives me error with 25.0.03.

Comment: You need to install them...use Android SDK manager.

Comment: Can you give us your MainActivity.java file?  Or at the very least the top 32 lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've followed all of the steps in the [Getting Started guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html).  Specifically, go to the "Getting Started with Native Code" tab and ensure you not only have all of the dependencies installed, but that you also have your environment variables set up correctly, i.e.:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

EDIT:

It looks like you may be missing a few imports, specifically:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
```

I'm also not sure where `MainReactPackage` is coming from on line 29 of your `MainActivity`, but I assume it's a custom `ReactPackage` in your application, and you would need to import that as well.

In addition, you seem to be mixing code from what should be in your `MainApplication.java` file.  The `gitPackages()` function you have defined should be moved there, as that function is defined in `ReactApplication` rather than `ReactActivity`.

EDIT 2:

Here is an example of what your `MainActivity` should look like:

```
package com.myapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "myapp";
    }
}
```

And this is what your `MainApplication` might look like:

```
package com.myapp;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
  CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager)
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Comment: no it didnt. That is error I mentioned in my second update through pastebin links.

Comment: Did you see the rest of my answer?  It seems you're missing imports and have functions defined in the wrong class.