# Android Release Build Failed in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

[image: The error in terminal]I encountered the following problem after running **./gradlew assembleRelease** command. Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' property '$1' during up-to-date check.

> Could not list contents of '/Users/sateweb/Desktop/desktop/Prayer/WeR1Peace/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/.bin/sane'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.

I already tried removing and installing node_modules and also tried cleaning the build folder and rebuilding it again. But the problem persists.

my android/build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my android/app/build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile


project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wer1peace"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->

            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    //Google Signin
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1' // should be at least 9.0.0

    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apisauce": "^1.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.12.1",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.7",
    "react-native-device-info": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.1",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.53.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/resources/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

```
package com. app_name;
import android.os.Bundle; // here
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen; // here
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        MainApplication.getCallbackManager().onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashScreenTheme);  // here
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "app_name";
    }
}
```

```
package com.app_name;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerPackage;
import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;  //new
//Google Signin
import co.apptailor.googlesignin.RNGoogleSigninPackage;  // <--- import


public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
  }

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new RNGoogleSigninPackage(),
            new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new SplashScreenReactPackage(),
            new ImagePickerPackage(),
            new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
            new RNDeviceInfo()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
     // FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

I expected to build the release version of app without any issue.

Instead I encountered the error mentioned above.

**SOLUTION:** I finally figured it out I needed to explicitly set the compile SDK version in project level build.gradle file through this code snippet

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing your node_modules folder and installing dependencies again? What is the content of your package.json?

Comment: I edited my code and kept the package.json file

Answer (score 0):

What version of RN are you using? You could upgrade to React Native to **latest version** to fix the issue.
or You can try deleting the **.bin** folder inside your **node_modules** and **re-install** dependencies again.

Comment: Though i was able to solve this error by **rm -rf node_modules** and **yarn** This generated another issue of *react-native-fbsdk* stating               **Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt**

Comment: So your issue fixed by remove node_modules, fine, next you getting _fbsdk_ error, for this @KevinGrot has explained very good. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488207/react-native-fbsdk-build-errors?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Well thank for your response but that didn't solve my problem also i am uploading my both main class files for reference in the edit

Comment: Getting the error*error: failed linking references. What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-fbsdk:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt*